# Tensor value, tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I have a set $(v_{1},...,v_{5})$

I wanted to find value of $A \otimes B - B \otimes A \in T_{1}^{1}(V) $, where

$A = e^{1} \otimes e^{2} + e^{2} \otimes e^{3} + e^{2} \otimes e^{2}$

$B = e^{1} \otimes e^{1} \otimes (e^{1} - e^{3})$

$v_{1} = e_{1}, \quad v_{2} = e_{1} + e_{2} \quad v_{3} = e_{2} + e_{3}, \quad v_{4}=v_{5}=e_{2}$

Particular commentary would be appreciated.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ seem to be elements of $V\otimes V$. Then $A\otimes B$ would be an element of $V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V$. Are you sure you are writing it right? Also, what stopping you from doing the direct calculation? Just expand the product.

Comment: Where did $T_1^1(V)$ come from? Show us what you have done and ask a specific question where you are stuck.

Comment: Just expanding the product works. Thanks.